# Where to find res stock Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-7.1-nougat, android-shortcut

I want to find this resource layout:

[image]

Well, starting from the code of Android 7.1 shortcuts classes I trawled a bit all over the Android code, but I can not find the layout (or class) that draws the layout in image, many times I searched layouts that are non-existent, but the classes use it..

Can you tell me if I'm wrong approach if they are hidden and we can not see them or what?

Comment: AFAIK, the UI for app shortcuts is rendered by the home screen. Assuming that your screenshot is from the proprietary Pixel Launcher, then the Pixel Launcher would have those layouts.

Comment: So I was looking in the wrong place, but I wonder you can see the launcher of the code? @CommonsWare

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what "the launcher of the code" is. If you mean "the source code of the Pixel Launcher", that is a proprietary app, not an open source app.

Comment: Yes, sorry, and thanks for the help, the only thing left to do is implement the layout..